# Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to code a GMM function. The problem is that for the next loop I get the next error:

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts.
```

The error is related to the loop part that starts here. Below the loop you have the whole code. I was searching on the Internet and I tried many things, but I really do not understand why I have this problem. I also checked the size of each variable included, they are all of (694,1), and I am pretty sure that the size of each one of the variable specified is the right one.

```
% 
for i=1:T-3      
         % g(i,1)=((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1;
          a(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1);
          b(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1)*dj(i);      
          c(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1)*consumpt(i);


%     function [q] = Q(param,M,data,cond)

   T = length(data);

  % Population moments
  % [PMvec] = populat0ion_moments(param);
   %sigma = param(2);  
   alpha = param(1);
   beta = param(2);
   b = param(3);
  % c = ( data(3:end,1) + b*(data(2:end-1,1)))./(data(2:end-1,1) + b*(data(1:end-2,1) + b*( data(3:end,1)) + b*(data(2:end-1,1))./(data(2:end-1,1) + b*(data(1:end-2,1)));
   dj= data(2:end-2,2)./data(1:end-3,2);
   cpr = data(1:end-3,1) 
   ctd = data(2:end-2,1)
   ctw = data(3:end-1,1)
   ctw2= data(4:end, 1)

   c1 = (ctw+b.*ctd)./(ctd+b.*cpr);   
   c2 = (ctw2+b.*ctw)./(ctd+b.*cpr);


    consumpt = data(2:end-2,1)./data(1:end-3,1);
   [row,col] = size(cpr);
      djinst = dj(1:row,1);
   %z = [1 consumpt djinst]

    a = zeros(1, 694);
    b = zeros(1, 694);
    c = zeros(1, 694);
   for i=1:T-4

         % g(i,1)=((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1;
          a(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1);

          b(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1)*dj(i);

 c(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta (c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1)*consumpt(i);
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts 

Error in Q (line 43) 

 a(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (bbeta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (bbeta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1);
```

Comment: Please, tell us where the error is

Comment: This is the error I got.. Thank you
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts
Error in Q (line 43)
          a(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1);

Comment: what is the `size()` of everything in the right of the `=`

Comment: the size is (694,1)

Comment: This needs a [mcve] for us to help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I formatted your error code with code formatting. Note that's how both code and error code should be formatted, not as quotes (the formatting for the yellow background). Quote formatting should be used for quoting regular text (for example, the W3C states that [quote formatted text here]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are reassigning `b` from a scalar to a vector and that might be causing the problem.

```
b = param(3);
...
b = zeros(1, 694);
```

Comment: You were right. The only think I changeg was this part of the code, by changing "b" by the actual "d".  d(:,i)=(((beta.*((c1(i).^(-alpha)) + (b*beta*(c2(i)).^(-alpha))).*dj(i)) - (b*beta.*(c1(i)).^(-alpha))) - 1)*dj(i);  And it works. But now I get another problem. I will try to solve it. I hope to be able to deal with it. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any other issues. Could you mark the check next to my answer if it solved your problem? Thanks!